# PHP script for sending email

Tags: php, email

I am trying to create a simple PHP script that will send email to my gmail account, the script is working and sending the email, but everything appears in the subject line as such:

> from: me
>
> to:   me@gmail.com
>
> date: Wed, Mar 28, 2018 at 10:20 AM
>
> subject:  Here is what was sent: Name : me<br>Emailme@gmail.com<br>Message: Testing this form 1<br>
>
> mailed-by:    my.server.cloud

And nothing in the body of the email! I am definitely doing something wrong, so here is my code:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))

  {

  //send email

  $to = "me@gmail.com";

  $name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;

  $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;

  $from = $_REQUEST['email'] ;

  $subject = "Email request from " ;

  $message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;

  $header = "From: $from";

  mail( $to, $from, "$subject: $name", $message, $header );

  echo "Thank you $name for using our mail form";

  }

else

//if "email" is not filled out, display the form

  {

  echo "<p>Your message was not sent, please click the back button on your 
browser and correct the mistakes</p>;

  }
```

Comment: I suggest you look **very closely** at the arguments for PHP's [`mail($to, $subject, $message, $additional_headers, $additional_parameters)`](http://php.net/manual/function.mail.php) function

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. Thx all worked now after taking a closer look at the string...

Answer (score 0):

Change your

```
 mail( $to, $from, "$subject: $name", $message, $header );
```

to

```
 mail( $to, "$subject: $name", $message, $header );
```

Remember to only put the from-address into the header, not as an additional parameter

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. Thank you, yes you are right, it all worked now.